# Using VBA to drag formula across columns until it gets to todays date

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a VBA code that allows me to copy/drag/paste a formula across columns until it gets to todays date. For example on Sheet 1 Column A-Z are individual dates 1/1/24-1/26/24 and I need the formula in row 2 to copy along each column until todays date which is on Sheet2 A1.

I feel like this is simple but for some reason am struggling

Comment: Hint: find today's date in row 1 first. You can use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` for that.

Comment: Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Comment: Use the macro recorder and do this manually at first. That should point you in the right direction